# How to check if a variable equals to part of one of the columns in a table in the Database?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example I have a variable `$num = 123;` and another one called `$name=joe;' , and there is a Database that contains a table called "data" and inside this table there are two columns (num [type=varchar(255)] - name[type=varchar(255)]) .

For example these query exists in the DB :
num = 123456 , name = joe

How to make a check that the first "3" numbers equals the $num variable and the name equals variable $name ?

I tried this but it didn't work:
`SELECT * FROM data Where SUBSTRING(num , 0 , 3) = '123' AND name = 'joe'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, substring indexing starts at 1:

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(num , 1 , 3) = '123' AND name = 'joe'
```

But `LEFT()` or `LIKE` would more commonly be used:

```
WHERE LEFT(num , 3) = '123' AND name = 'joe'
WHERE num = '123%' AND name = 'joe'
```

The advantage of `LIKE` is that it can make use of an index . . . even one on `(name, num)`.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL `substring()` function is 1-based, not 0-based, so this should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM data Where SUBSTRING(num , 1 , 3) = '123' AND name = 'joe'
```